# How to print a sequence from 0 to N using recursion with only one parameter in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I know how to write a recursive function to print from N to 0: N, N-1, ... 1, 0

But somehow I get stuck on doing the same thing but in increasing order from 0, 1, ... , N.

This is my code for the N to 0:

```
int main() {
    int n = 4;
    backward(n);
    return 0;
}

void backward(int n) {

    if (n == 0) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }

    else if (n > 0) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
        backward(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Other option is to simply start with 0 until N with the same code, but increase counter for next iteration. However, this would require a recursive function of 2 parameters.

Comment: This needs a not uncommon change of approach from “process this item, then the following ones” to “process the previous items, then this one”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your recursive call before `cout`.

You'll recurse all the way to `n` without printing anything.
Then, on the way back out, it will print out `n` in ascending order.

```
int main() {
    int n = 4;
    forward(n);
    return 0;
}

void forward(int n) {

    if (n == 0) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }

    else if (n > 0) {
        forward(n - 1);
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to swap `std::cout << n << " ";` and `backward(n - 1);` around.  With the print statement first, your print the value of `n` and then go on to the next "iteration".  If you instead call the function recursively first, and then print the value of `n` you will get all the way to the zero case, print zero, return to the one case, print one, and keep going until you return to the `n` case where you then print `n`.  So `forward` is just

```
void forward(int n) {

    if (n == 0) {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }

    else if (n > 0) {
        forward(n - 1);
        std::cout << n << " "; // print n only after everything else has printed
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int main() {
    int n = 4;
    forward(n);
    std::cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}

void forward(int n) {
    if ( n == -1)     
     return;       
    forward(n - 1); 
   std::cout<<n<<" ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.